# material design - TabLayout - set a particular tab/TabItem background color unselected

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I have been working on material **TabLayout** and there is a condition where I have to unselect all tabs at once. I know that isn't possible and violates material guidelines. So I thought of maybe changing the particular background color of current tab to show as unselected. I set `TabLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext, R.drawable.selector_state_reversed))` but it didn't work. I also used `TabLayout.setSelected(false)` but it only worked for the first time after the fragment is created. Any guide, help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you cannot un-select all the tabs in the TabLayout concept. In TabLayout concept, at least one tab must be chosen at a time. That apply to all areas (website, mobile app or desktop applications).

Comment: My suggestion is return back to First Tab when you have a condition of un-select the current tab.

Comment: @Steve.NayLinAung That condition works when I am at first tab itself :) ,so I thought maybe there could be workaround to somehow let the user know that the tab is unselected.

Comment: Anyways I am already performing actions on tab reselection. Thanks btw.